# In silverlight how do you scrub a string

Tags: .net, silverlight, special-characters

I have a string that looks like this " Into" and I can't figure out what the " " value is just before the Into.  It's not a space, it's not an enter.  At least i don't think so.  I've tried  doing a replace to get rid of it..

So now i'm just trying to figure out what that character value is.  Convert.int32 doesn't get it done... What can i use to get rid of that character... I guess i could write a function that would loop through the alphabet and do it that way.. but figured there was a better way.

thanks
shannon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Trim() which removes all leading and trailing whitespace from a string?

e.g. (C#)

```
string cleanString = dirtyString.Trim();
```

To find the ASCII val of the "mystery" character:

```
int charVal = (int)dirty.ToCharArray()[0];
```

P.S. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to ask about using C# or .NET to scrub a string?

**EDIT**

```
// algorithm for removing weird char from string

    string dirtyString = " sdfsf ";

    // get the offending character:
    char dirtyChar = dirtyString.ToCharArray()[0];

    // replace offending character with something known like an asterisk
    string cleanString = dirtyString.Replace(dirtyChar, '*');

    // remove asterisk from string
    cleanString = cleanString.Replace("*", "");
```